# Write the ODE $\ddot{x}+k\dot{x}+V'(x)=0$ as a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Write the ODE $\ddot{x}+k\dot{x}+V'(x)=0$ as a system.

Here, $\dot{x}$ is differentiation with respect to $t$. I wrote this as $$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}\\\dot{u}\\\dot{1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&-k&-V'(x)\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\u\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\dot{x}=u$.

Is this the correct representation. I'm not sure because of the extra row that I had to add to the system.

Comment: You can't totally write it as a linear system because it isn't entirely a linear system; about the only way to treat it as a linear system is to move $V'(x)$ into a forcing, but that's a bit of a strange way to do it because it depends on the state.

Comment: @Ian- The actual question says write it as a "state" instead of "linear state". I don't know if that changes things.

Comment: Then just means writing it in the form $\dot{x}=u,\dot{u}=\dots$, where the second equation can look like anything. It doesn't really make sense to write it in matrix form when the system isn't linear anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$\ddot x + k \dot x + V'(x) = 0 \tag 1$

cannot in general be wrtten as a *linear system* (as proposed in the original question, before the present edits were in effect), for the simple reason that $V'(x)$ is not in general a linear function of the variable $x$.

We *can* however write (1) as a *first order system*, in which only the *first derivative(s)* of the *state variable(s)* are present, by denoting 
$\dot x$ by $y$:

$y = \dot x, \tag 2$

whence

$\dot y = \ddot x; \tag 3$

then (1) may be expressed in the form

$\dot y + ky + V'(x) = 0, \tag 4$

that is,

$\dot y = -ky - V'(x); \tag 5$

this together with (2) form a first order system in the two variables $x(t)$ and $y(t)$; such systems are often writen in *vector-field* form; that is, we may define a vector field $\mathbf X(x, y)$ on $\Bbb R^2$ by

$\mathbf X(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ -ky - V'(x) \end{pmatrix}; \tag 6$

then setting

$\mathbf r = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \tag 7$

we have

$\dot{\mathbf r} = \begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ -ky - V'(x) \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf X(x, y). \tag 8$